# I want to build cgreen on Cygwin64

Tags: cygwin

I installed Cygwin64 and wanted to install Cgreen too.

I input command 'make' at Cygwin64.
I saw this error.

[image]

I think this is a problem about makefile.
I don't know how to fix it exactly.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT using the Cygwin version of Make.

```
$ type make
make is /usr/bin/make

$ make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-cygwin
...
```

so or you have not installed the make package and to verify it you
should use cygcheck

```
$ cygcheck -c make
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
make                 4.3-1          OK
```

or you have modified the PATH to have additional directories before the Cygwin one

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/Marco/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/lapack:/usr/sbin:...
```

Comment: thanks, matzeri.

As you were told me, I installed make package. and make command recognized on Cygwin. but another problem happened.

Comment: Do not put screenshot, copy and past relevant errors. Have you installed a compiler ? like gcc.core ?

Answer (score 0):

The cgreen package release 1.3.0 has some issues. Clearly it was not tested as stand alone before release. See also:

https://github.com/cgreen-devs/cgreen/issues/234

To build from git source, you need to install `make`, `cmake` and `git` packages, plus of course the C compiler `gcc-core`

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cgreen-devs/cgreen.git
Cloning into 'cgreen'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 203, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (203/203), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (146/146), done.
remote: Total 9958 (delta 96), reused 133 (delta 56), pack-reused 9755
Receiving objects: 100% (9958/9958), 2.81 MiB | 6.07 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7024/7024), done.

$ cd cgreen

$ make
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
...
[100%] Linking C shared library cygcgreen_runner_tests.dll
make[3]: Leaving directory '/pub/tmp/cgreen/build'
[100%] Built target cgreen_runner_tests
make[2]: Leaving directory '/pub/tmp/cgreen/build'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/pub/tmp/cgreen/build'
```

On my system it passes all tests

```
$ make test
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /pub/tmp/cgreen/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/pub/tmp/cgreen/build'
...
25/25 Test #25: cgreen_runner_multiple_libraries ...................................   Passed    1.15 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 25

Total Test time (real) =  52.58 sec
make[4]: Leaving directory '/pub/tmp/cgreen/build'
Built target check
make[3]: Leaving directory '/pub/tmp/cgreen/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/pub/tmp/cgreen/build'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/pub/tmp/cgreen/build'
```

As alternative you can use the proposal reported in the issue

```
$ tar -xf cgreen-1.3.0.tar.gz
$ cd cgreen-1.3.0
$ sed -i -e "s/^get_filename_component/\# get_filename_component/" CMakeLists.txt
$ make
```

Comment: Thank you! this problem is gcc compiler! :)

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: This problem was caused by my not installing gcc c++ package.